# Rails Tutorial Chapter 8 - undefined local variable or method `signin_path'

Tags: railstutorial.org

I'm getting the following rSpec failed tests error.

What did I do wrong?

Many thanks..

1) Authentication signin page Failure/Error: before { visit signin_path } NameError: undefined local variable or method signin_path' for # # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:8:inblock (3 levels) in '

2) Authentication signin page Failure/Error: before { visit signin_path } NameError: undefined local variable or method signin_path' for # # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:8:inblock (3 levels) in '

#### session_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController 
    def 
      new 
    end 

    def 
      create 
    end

    def 
      destroy 
    end 
  end
```

#### routes.rb:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do 
resources :users 
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

root to: 'static_pages#home'

match '/signup', to: 'users#new' 
match '/signin', to: 'sessions#new' 
match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

#### authentication_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

subject { page }

describe "signin page" do before { visit signin_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign in') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
end
```

end

Comment: you should wrap your code in the proper 'code' formatting. easiest way is to select your code block and hit control + k. it's make your post look less ugly and probably more likely that somebody will answer it.

Comment: thanks MasterKrang. ctrl-k-ed.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue and restarting guard/spork after I created my routes solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the `signin` route to `routes.rb` and not restart spork (assuming you're using it) before running your tests?

Comment: I got the same error as the OP and this was my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you run `rake routes` from your console and show the output